# Copy Files From TFS 2010 To An Arbitrary Folder

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the list of files in a particular changeset and then extract them from TFS and place in some arbitrary folder that is not my local workspace.

So far I am able to parse out the files changed from a collection of code found across the internet. Now, what I want to do is copy those files and put in "C:\mypath\tostuff\toworkon".

Here is how I am getting the files:

```
param(
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
     [string] $changesets = $(throw 'Usage: Get-Changeset-Files ''changesets'''),
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
     [string] $path,
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
     [string] $VOSversion,
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
     [string] $environment
)

process
{
     # get TFS object
     $tfs = get-tfs;

     # build up list of file items    
     $fileItems = @();

     $changesets.Split(',') | foreach {
       $tfs.vcs.GetChangeset($_).Changes | foreach {
           if($path.length -gt 0) {
               if($_.Item.ServerItem.Contains($path)) {
                   if($fileItems -notcontains $_.Item.ServerItem) {
                       $fileItems += $_.Item.ServerItem;
                   }
               }
           } else {
               if($fileItems -notcontains $_.Item.ServerItem) {
                   $fileItems += $_.Item.ServerItem;
               }
           }
       }
     }

   $downloadFolder = 'C:\mypath\tostuff\toworkon'
   foreach ($element in $fileItems) {
    $fileItem = $tfs.vcs.GetItem($element);
    $contents = ( [io.streamreader]$fileItem.DownloadFile() ).ReadToEnd();
    $contents.CopyTo();
   }

   return $fileItems | Sort-Object;

}
```

My issue is the `$contents.CopyTo()` section. I know that isn't correct. That is the part I am stuck on. My goal is for whatever path is in the `$contents` the files are copied all to one location - I do not need to preserve folder paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more digging and realizing that you cant really do `$var1 + "\" + $var2` and have it act like I thought I came to this solution:

```
if(Test-Path -Path $downloadFolder ){
    if (!($downloadFolder.EndsWith("\"))) {
        $targetFolder = $downloadFolder + "\";
    } else {
        $targetFolder = $downloadFolder;
    }

    #echo $targetFolder;
    foreach ($element in $fileItems) {
        $fileItem = $tfs.vcs.GetItem($element);
        $elementSplit = $element.Split('/');
        $fileName = $elementSplit[$elementSplit.length - 1];
        echo $fileName;
        $contents = ( [io.streamreader]$fileItem.DownloadFile() ).ReadToEnd();
        #echo $targetFolder$fileName;
        $contents | Out-File $targetFolder$fileName -Force;
    }
}
```

The important part is:

```
$contents | Out-File $targetFolder$fileName -Force;
```

I learn something new everyday.